# Rails server not starting with web sockets and redis options in rake task.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, redis, rake

I have to use websockets in my rake task and for that I changed my **event.rb** to

```
 config.synchronize = true  
  # Uncomment and edit to point to a different redis instance.
  # Will not be used unless standalone or synchronization mode
  # is enabled.
 config.redis_options = {:host => 'localhost', :port => '3000'}
```

and when I start my rails server I get this error:

```
! Invalid request
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@socialmail/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/connection/synchrony.rb:115:in `read':  Got 'Protocol error, got "H" as reply type byte' as initial reply byte. If you're in a forking environment, such as Unicorn, you need to connect to Redis after forking.  (Redis::ProtocolError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for the question, I personally couldn't get a rake task of mine to post to a websocket channel I had open on my rails server. Your synchronize command helped (along with starting a Redis server locally).

Your problem through - seems like you're pointing to 3000. Is that your rails server or the Redis instance? If you're running it locally, I'd omit that line.